# a database error occurred column 'title' cannot be null

Tags: php, codeigniter

here is my site_model code
get all data from database and insert data into database using Html form
please help i don't know where i do mistake

```
class Site_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    // get all data from database
    public function get_records()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('user_data');
        return $query->result();
    }    

    // add records into database by form
    public function add_record($formData)
    {
        $this->db->insert('user_data', $formData);
    }
}
```

than i load model into controller and get values in an array. and after create an array to send form values into database

```
class Site extends CI_Controller
{
    var $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Site_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //get data into array from model
        $data = $this->data;
        $data['user_info'] = $this->Site_model->get_records();

        // get data from html form and send to database
        $formData = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('post_title'),
            'description' => $this->input->post('post_descrip')
            );

        // send record to model
        $this->Site_model->add_record($formData);
        $this->load->view('crud_viw', $data);
    }
}
```

my view code look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Crud</title>
</head>
<body>

    // Html form to send values to database
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title" name="post_title"></input>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Description" name="post_descrip">       </input>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </from>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check the value for `post_title` after posting in index() function

Comment: @pathik when i echo "<pre>"; print_r($formData); exit; it show me an array with values that i have insert by html form...but when i want to send this data to my model function then i got error "Column 'title' cannot null "

Comment: check in model that you are getting the values or not

Comment: @pathik but how to check values in model..i am new in ci i have no experience yet

Comment: check the last query by: echo $this->db->last_query(); die();

Comment: @pathik sorry i didn't get it...it show only "SELECT * FROM `user_data`"

Comment: what is the query printed?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `user_data`

Comment: what is the `$formData` value in `Model`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your index method as below. You only have to enter data when post event occur

```
public function index()
    {
        //get data into array from model
        $data = $this->data;
        $data['user_info'] = $this->Site_model->get_records();
        if($this->input->post()){  //<--- add this condition

        // get data from html form and send to database
        $formData = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('post_title'),
            'description' => $this->input->post('post_descrip')
            );

        // send record to model
        $this->Site_model->add_record($formData);
       }
        $this->load->view('crud_viw', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your database your column "title" should be not null..so mark "title" as not null in database..
Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to prevent getting the `a database error occurred column 'title' cannot be null` is use ternary operator`(?:)`.If you have not posted value it will inserts empty string.

```
 $formData = array(
            'title' => isset($this->input->post('post_title'))?$this->input->post('post_title'):" ",
            'description' => isset($this->input->post('post_descrip'))?$this->input->post('post_descrip'):" "
            );
```

Hope it works.